# Subsetting dataframes removing false values

Tags: r

I have a data of following sort:

```
head(df)
```

[image]

Sometimes I have value "Nan" in the answer column.
[image]

What I wish to do create a separate dataframe of all rows with this value and one without.

I used the following code:

```
dfwith <-df[ !grepl("Nan", df$answer) , ]
dfwithout <-df[ grepl("Nan", df$answer) , ]
```

But I get incorrect results, I don't understand why, where am I going wrong.
Thanks in advance. Please help.

Edit:

```
> dput(droplevels(head(df)))
structure(list(X.run.number. = c(16L, 9L, 3L, 18L, 1L, 19L), 
    density = c(0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52), k = c(100L, 
    100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), knt = c(2900L, 1700L, 500L, 
    2900L, 500L, 2900L), threshold = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.1, 
    0.5), X.step. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), answer = structure(c(4L, 
    5L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("100.2767857", "106.9588889", 
    "107.1467647", "53.13833333", "64.54785714", "95.61115385"
    ), class = "factor"), percent = c(16.04938272, 18.51851852, 
    38.27160494, 34.56790123, 11.11111111, 45.67901235)), .Names = c("X.run.number.", 
"density", "k", "knt", "threshold", "X.step.", "answer", "percent"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Edit 2:

```
> dput(droplevels(tail(df)))
structure(list(X.run.number. = c(4488L, 4509L, 4502L, 4537L, 
4530L, 4544L), density = c(0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52
), k = c(600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 600L), knt = c(19700L, 
23300L, 22100L, 28100L, 26900L, 29300L), threshold = c(0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1), X.step. = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), answer = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "\"Nan\"", class = "factor"), percent = c(11.11111111, 
12.34567901, 6.172839506, 8.641975309, 11.11111111, 11.11111111
)), .Names = c("X.run.number.", "density", "k", "knt", "threshold", 
"X.step.", "answer", "percent"), row.names = 4545:4550, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: How's your first `grepl` differs from the second?

Comment: @DavidArenburg Oh sorry! Check now please

Comment: by "incorrect results" you of course mean ..

Comment: Instead of the image, I would recommend providing the actual data.

Comment: @rawr It should exclude more rows with "Nan". It does fewer. Idk why.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Sorry cant provide the data, it's unpublished right now, and I don't think my advisor would agree.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia  Based on this `v1 <- c(17.47113636, 'Nan', 18.83678571, 'Nan', 'Nan'); grepl('Nan', v1)` works

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia You don't have to show the exact data.  Just an example that mimics your original dataset.

Comment: @akrun It's double quotes. Is that the problem? I doubt it.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia You have to show few lines of your data using `dput`. ie. `dput(head(yourdata)` that includes the "Nan" values.  Also I assume that the "answer" column is "character" class

Comment: @akrun It is a .csv file I read. I generated the data somewhere.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia  It just says you have a factor column. We are ready to help you if you can help us with showing few lines of your dataset using `dput`.

Comment: @akrun yeah I tried that but it command outputs a huge dataset which I am unable to copy here. dput(head(df)) . Any other way? Or am doing something wrong.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia Try  `dput(droplevels(head(yourdata)))` that includes 'Nan' values as well.

Comment: @akrun Okay ,Great! Check now.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia  But in that dataset, you don't have `Nan` Try again on `dput(droplevels(yourdata[4535:4539,]))`

Comment: @akrun sorry check now.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia  Based on the head and tail rows, I don't find any problem in subsetting your data with the same code you showed. `df1 <- droplevels(df[!grepl('Nan', df$answer),])`  May be the unused levels are creating you some problem. If that is the case, wrap it with `droplevels`

Comment: @akrun Sorry man it works. I was making stupid error somewhere. Thanks! anyways. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia  Glad to know it works.  May I know the mistake you did (just for curiosity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For only getting rows without NA, you can use:

```
dfwithout <- na.omit(df)
```

And if you need to change Nan to NA or NaN, you can use:

```
df <- gsub("Nan", "NA", df)
```

You can see which rows and columns have NA with:

```
which(is.na(df), arr.ind=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with you having NaN instead of NA.  Try this.

```
df[complete.cases(df), ]
```

Comment: I think the OP's dataset have "Nan" as character elements or may be something else.  So, this may not be helpful.